# Implementing Forms-Based Authentication

Tags: asp.net

I have a website for public users, but also have an admin part of about 10 pages, that I need to secure for website admin only.

If I implement Forms-Based Authentication on the 10 pages, will it also spread across the public part of the website too?   i.e. changes in web.config.

I want my website 3 security levels available to:

1. All public users (non registered)
2. Registered public users
3. Website Administrators

I was looking at this example (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301240) but it looks like it closes off public view for entire application!?!

Regards
Tea

Comment: Have a look at [How to: Implement Simple Forms Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdt4thhy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: @huMptyduMpty Your example looks like it locks out all public users?

Comment: It depends on where you put a web.config file with authentication sections - you can have more than one across your site.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the hassle altogether & create separate websites for admin & public inside a single web application project.

Answer (score 0):

Forms-based authentication gives you control over what is secured. So when you say "it looks like it closes off public view for entire application" that isn't true.

You can give only admin-users access to the 10 admin pages, and give access to all users to the public pages.

In the example you have the following:

```
<authorization>
   <deny users ="?" />
   <allow users = "*" />
</authorization>
```

If that is in the folder containing your admin pages, then anonymous users will not be allowed to access the pages. If you put that in the root folder then anonymous users won't be able to access any of your site.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be easier for you to allow/deny permission based on user role.

for example if you need all the users under admin role to be allowed and others to be restricted.

```
 <authorization>
    <allow roles="Admin" />
     <deny users="*" />
 </authorization>
```

Have a read about

[Managing Authorization Using Roles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ab2fxh0%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

[Use Role Manager in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647401.aspx#paght000013_step1)

[Assigning Roles to Users](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/roles/assigning-roles-to-users-cs)

Answer (score 0):

From the Web Site Administration Tool you can set users, roles and which pages they are allowed to access, including anonymous users, without getting into the code.

Here's the MSDN tool overview:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy40ytx0%28v=VS.100%29.aspx